# Show top X items of ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, filtering, collectionviewsource, collectionview

I have an `IcollectionView` property called `Suggestions` which is binded to a ListBox's `ItemsSource`.

I Use the following code to set it up

```
// Set up Suggestions collection for filtering purposes
var collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

collectionViewSource.Source = SomeCollection; // SomeCollection is of type IEnumerable!! 
// Create view
Suggestions = collectionViewSource.View;

Suggestions.Filter = new Predicate<object>(
                                       item =>
                                       item.ToString().StartsWith(SearchString, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
```

`SearchString` is binded to a TextBox's `Text` property, that whenever changes triggers `Suggestions.Refresh()` that refilters the collection.

This works well, but shows all the available items. how can I make it show only the top X items?

Comment: Tried `SomeCollection.Cast<string>().Take(X)` but then it filters only the top X items which is not what I want. I want it to filter the entire collection and only display the top X results ...

Comment: Could use yield to just return the first x  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just move your filter `Predicate` condition to the `SomeCollection.Where` clause?:

```
SomeCollection = SomeCollection.Where(item => item.ToString().StartsWith(
    SearchString, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).Take(10);
collectionViewSource.Source = SomeCollection;
```

Comment: Thanks, I Guess I could try it, but doesn't it take away the whole purpose of `ICollectionView`?

Comment: I just thought of another way that you could do this... add an index property to your data type and use filter `Predicate` like `i => i.Index <= 10)`.

Answer (score -1):

Associate Visibility with all the filtered items and set the visibility to true only for the Top X items or,

First filter all the items and put the top x items in another property and bind it to UI